# Ruby on Rails 3 gsub escapes the anchor of link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check a string and change any `@something` to link. So I have a helper function which consists of something like this:

```
def parse(content)
  content.gsub(/@[a-zA-z0-9]+\b/, link_to("#{$1}", user_path($1)) )
end
```

But the result is `<a href="/users/102"></a>`

The problem is :

1. The `<a href="/users/102"></a>` is a string, because somehow the `<` and `>` is escaped.
2. Why does `"#{$1}"` return nothing? Isn't it supposed to return whatever is checked upon, in this case `@something`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Rails HTML-escapes any content produced by a user-defined helper, unless you tell it not to. Try using `<%= raw parse(content) %>` in your view.
2. Quoting Pickaxe on `gsub`:

> If a string is used as the replacement, special variables from the match (such as $& and $1)
>   cannot be substituted into it, because substitution into the string occurs before the pattern match
>   starts. However, the sequences \1, \2, and so on, may be used to interpolate successive numbered
>   groups in the match, and \k<name> will substitute the corresponding named captures.

So you can't use `#{$1}` because `$1` isn't set until after the command has finished. Your best bet is probably to use the block form of gsub - in which case `$1` *is* set inside the block. Try:

```
def parse(content)
  content.gsub(/@[a-zA-z0-9]+\b/) {link_to($1, user_path($1))} 
end
```

Comment: I've tried you solution, but now the anchor text and the href are the same, i mean, $1 returns the same value which is : <a href="/users/102">/users/102</a> . Any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, i'm using block like this and it works now. { |str| link_to(str, $1)  } Thanks!